# Why doesn't sbt pick up the scoped value here?

Tags: scala, sbt

Looking through the getting started guide for scopes, it seems to imply that I should be able to do something like this:

(where Build.scala has the sampleKeyA/B/C/D from the [getting started guide](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Welcome))

```
sampleKeyA := "value 1"

sampleKeyA in compile := "value 2"

compile <<= (compile in Compile, sampleKeyA) map { (result, s) =>
  println("sample key: " + s)
  result
}
```

But when I run sbt compile, the value printed for sampleKeyA is "value 1", not "value 2" as I expect.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, defining *sampleKeyA in compile* is of course valid, since it scopes the setting to the *compile* task.

Second, you get *value 1*, because you are using *sampleKeyA* without the above scope. Change it to *sampleKeyA in compile* and you will get *value 2*.

To see this, just start an "empty" sbt session and execute the following:

```
> set SettingKey[String]("sampleKeyA") := "value 1"           
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to default-a57b70 (in build file:/Users/heiko/tmp/sbt/)
> set SettingKey[String]("sampleKeyA") in compile := "value 2"
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to default-a57b70 (in build file:/Users/heiko/tmp/sbt/)
> sampleKeyA                                                  
[info] value 1
> sampleKeyA(for compile)                                     
[info] value 2
```

Comment: Doesn't the fact that I'm running the compile command mean I'm in the "compile" scope, and references to sampleKeyA would use the more-specific version of "sampleKeyA in compile"?

Comment: No, there is no automatic application of a task scope to a setting. If you want _sampleKeyA_ to be scoped to the _compile_ scope, you have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

It picked `value 1` because `value 2` is scoped in compile, but you got the general version. If you wrote `sampleKeyA in Compile`, it would then work. Or, perhaps, `in compile` -- I think that declaration is incorrect, as the scope `compile` doesn't really exist.

Comment: I may have picked a confusing example in using "compile" - I really did want the lower-case version, since I wanted to scope to the task axis "compile", not the configuration "Compile".  I'm a bit confused about why you say "the scope compile doesn't really exist" - there's a "compile" command, and I thought that always means that there's a matching scope on the task axis (that sounds like I'm miswording this horribly).